# How can you eliminate duplicates from a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code:

```
 def lottery(s):
            return ''.join(x for x in s if x.isdigit()) or "One more run!"
```

Now when you print out the s, it only prints the numbers and when there are only letters, it prints "One more run". Everything up to this point is fine, although I also want it to not print duplicates. Meaning that when I put `print(lottery(4443))` it only prints out 1 four and not the 3 of them.

Answer (score 1):

Try a `set()` to eliminate duplicates (un-ordered) and back to list with `sorted`

```
def lottery(s):
            return ''.join(x for x in sorted(set(s)) if x.isdigit()) or "One more run!"

lottery('435435')
```

Orders are too crucial?

```
def lottery(s):
            return ''.join(x for x in dict.fromkeys(s) if x.isdigit()) or "One more run!"

lottery('435435')
```

Comment: Unless consistent order is important, you can use `list()` instead of `sorted()`.

Comment: @Barmar check edits for `dict.fromkeys`

Comment: Yes, solved, thank you!

Comment: Why are you creating a dictionary? You can simply loop over the set: `for x in set(s)`